# SFML 2.4.2 - Segmentation fault when drawing text

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, sfml

I'm getting a segfault when running this code. It could be a faulty index, but I'm puzzled, for the element I try to access exists, as shows the "cout" right before the "draw".

I use GCC : g++ -std=c++11 ./ellipse.cpp -o ./ellipse -Wfatal-errors  -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

I'll keep on searching, but any help will be appreciated.

Best regards,

MC

````
#include <iostream>
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
using namespace std;
struct ellipse
    {
    sf::Text ellipseTitle;
    };
vector<ellipse> initialize(vector<ellipse> ellipses,unsigned short numberOfEllipses)
    {
    sf::Font myFont;
    string myfontFileName="./media/Arial.ttf";
    if (!myFont.loadFromFile(myfontFileName))
        {
        cout << "Could not find the font " << myfontFileName << endl;
        }
    ellipse e;
    e.ellipseTitle.setFont(myFont);
    e.ellipseTitle.setCharacterSize(20);
    e.ellipseTitle.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
    for(int i=0;i<numberOfEllipses;i++)
        {
        e.ellipseTitle.setString("[Some text "+to_string(i)+"]");
        sf::FloatRect textRect = e.ellipseTitle.getLocalBounds();
        e.ellipseTitle.setOrigin(textRect.left + textRect.width/2.0f,textRect.top  + textRect.height/2.0f);
        e.ellipseTitle.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(100,100+(20*i)));
        ellipses.push_back(e);
        }
    return ellipses;
    }
int main()
    {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640,480), "Demo",sf::Style::Default);
    unsigned short numberOfEllipses=11;
    vector<ellipse> ellipses;
    ellipses=initialize(ellipses,numberOfEllipses);
    sf::Event myEvent;
    while (window.isOpen())
        {
        while (window.pollEvent(myEvent))
            {
            if (myEvent.type == sf::Event::EventType::Closed)
                {
                window.close();
                }
            }
        window.clear();
        for(ellipse e:ellipses)
            {
            cout << "title " << e.ellipseTitle.getString().toAnsiString() << endl;
            window.draw(e.ellipseTitle);
            }
        window.display();
        }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    } ```
````

Comment: Read reference about `Text::setFont` very carefully - [link](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Text.php#a2927805d1ae92d57f15034ea34756b81). *the text doesn't store its own copy of the font, but rather keeps a pointer to the one that you passed to this function. If the font is destroyed and the text tries to use it, the behavior is undefined.* Your `ellipse` should also keep `Font` for `Text`.

Comment: Oh, yes ! That was so obvious I did not see it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks really. Searching a little more (knowing how to name the problem), I saw it was a really common mistake. Here is the corrected code :

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
using namespace std;
struct ellipse
    {
    sf::Text ellipseTitle;
    };
vector<ellipse> initialize(vector<ellipse> ellipses,unsigned short numberOfEllipses,sf::Font& myFont)
    {
    ellipse e;
    e.ellipseTitle.setFont(myFont);
    e.ellipseTitle.setCharacterSize(20);
    e.ellipseTitle.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
    for(int i=0;i<numberOfEllipses;i++)
        {
        e.ellipseTitle.setString("[Some text "+to_string(i)+"]");
        sf::FloatRect textRect = e.ellipseTitle.getLocalBounds();
        e.ellipseTitle.setOrigin(textRect.left + textRect.width/2.0f,textRect.top  + textRect.height/2.0f);
        e.ellipseTitle.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(100,100+(20*i)));
        ellipses.push_back(e);
        }
    return ellipses;
    }
int main()
    {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640,480), "Demo",sf::Style::Default);
    unsigned short numberOfEllipses=11;
    sf::Font myFont;
    string myfontFileName="./media/Arial.ttf";
    if (!myFont.loadFromFile(myfontFileName))
        {
        cout << "Could not find the font " << myfontFileName << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    vector<ellipse> ellipses;
    ellipses=initialize(ellipses,numberOfEllipses,myFont);
    sf::Event myEvent;
    while (window.isOpen())
        {
        while (window.pollEvent(myEvent))
            {
            if (myEvent.type == sf::Event::EventType::Closed)
                {
                window.close();
                }
            }
        window.clear();
        for(ellipse e:ellipses)
            {
            cout << "title " << e.ellipseTitle.getString().toAnsiString() << endl;
            window.draw(e.ellipseTitle);
            }
        window.display();
        }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }```
````